# Need For Large Executor Memory If Block size is 128 MB

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a question regarding spark. I am using spark 2.2 and as per my knowledge each executor spins up taks and executes the task. Each task corresponds to a partition. Default number of partition is based on default parallelism and the file size/Default Block Size. So considering a file size of 1 GB and a cluster of 4 executors each of which can spin up 2 tasks (2 core). As per calculation the executor memory should be about 256 MB (2 tasks each task operating on 128 MB block)+ 384 MB overhead. However If I run the code with this size as executor memory the performance is slow. If I give executor memory of 1.5 GB (considering some calculations on rdd) still the performance is slow. Only when I increase the executor memory to 3GB the performance is Good.

Can someone explain 
1. why do we need so much executor memory when we work on only 128 MB of data at a time. 
2. How do we calculate the optimum executor memory needed for the job

Thanks for your help

Comment: In memory processing entails more than reading in a file. E.g. shuffling due to JOIN, groupByKey.

Comment: Agree , but that shouldn't more than double the block size, If block size is 128MB the other operations like sorting etc will take lets say 200 MB. even then the execution is slow.

Comment: Size of record on disk and in memory may differ considerable. Use SizeEstimator or cache the input rdd to find the size of rdd in memory. This will be the size of input rdd. You will also have to account for many temporary objects created by executors when a transformation is applied on RDD.

Comment: Whatever be the transformation to process 128 MB we shouldn't require 1GB. Also lets say we just read from a file and read to another file without any transformation still then from what I have seen we still require a lot of executor memory to process the 128 MB block